# What can you do to find all the matching elements in an array... how do you implement?

Tags: ruby

What can you do to find all the matching elements in an array... how do you implement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by matching exactly? Do you want to compare each item to something?
Ruby provides a handful of methods depending on what you specifically want. You can find them in the documentation 
https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Array.html

https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Enumerable.html

You could use `select` for instance and hand the condition to a block.